# Round Robin Assignments matching on Zip Codes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Searching through stackoverflow, I was able to assign my employees to customers on a round robin basis, using the query below:

In `SQL Server`:

```
WITH    с AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY (CustomerID) AS rn
        FROM    customers
        ),
        s AS
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ORDER BY (EmployeeID) AS rn
        FROM    employees
        )
SELECT  c.*, s.*
FROM    с
JOIN    s
ON      s.rn =
        (с.rn - 1) %
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    employees
        ) + 1
```

However, I am wanting to go a bit further and assign my employees based on their location in relation to a customer. Here is an example:

```
Customers
--CustomerID  
--StoreZip (I matched the closest store to each customer)

Salesperson  
--EmployeeID  
--EmployeeZip
```

So, if I have 15 customers and 5 salespeople, I would like the end result to look something like this:

```
CustomerID -- StoreZip -- EmployeeID -- EmployeeZip  
1          --  28031   --      2     --    28031 
2          --  28031   --      3     --    28031 
3          --  28031   --      8     --    28031  
4          --  32216   --      4     --    32216
5          --  32216   --      15    --    32216  
6          --  32216   --      6     --    32216  
7          --  32216   --      12    --    32216  
8          --  32216   --      1     --    32216  
9          --  28262   --      5     --    28262
10         --  28262   --      13    --    28262
11         --  28262   --      9     --    28262  
12         --  28262   --      7     --    28262  
13         --  28203   --      10    --    28203
14         --  28203   --      14    --    28203  
15         --  28203   --      11    --    28203
```

etc...

Comment: I think your first code block has a typo, you're selecting from employees, but ordering on CustomerId?

More importantly, what happens when a customer has a ZIP that no employee has, or vice versa, so there's no obvious match? Or what happens if there are multiples, do they just get split up across all of them?

Comment: Oops, I had entered in the incorrect field and edited the post. When a customer has no match to an employee, I leave it null and have a separate script to assign a specific set of employees to customers not near a store. If the employee is not near a customer then they do not get assigned to anyone (this is for a specific set of customers). My question is how to assign employees on a round robin basis (as the query above does), but separated by zip code. In other words, if there are multiple employees that match one store, they each get one before anyone gets assigned two+